# Access references in structs / class

Tags: swift, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to implement control over iOS UI elements using a loop over an array.  However, it looks like where I apply the changes to a frame item, it's being applied to a value, rather than a reference.  If I make the same changes on the UI element, itself, it works.

In C, I'd say, `&someElement` and dereference it during processing.  How do I achieve the same thing in Swift?

```
class UIComponentLocationStruct {
 var control: CGRect  // might be a UILabel, UIButton, or some other item
 var xOffset: Int
 var yOffset: Int

 init( control:CGRect, xOffset:Int, yOffset:Int ){
   self.control = control
   self.xOffset = xOffset
   self.yOffset = yOffset
  }
}

class rowOfComponents {
  var yOffset: Int
  var components: [UIComponentLocationStruct]

  init( yOffset:Int, components:[UIComponentLocationStruct]? ){
    self.yOffset = yOffset
    self.components = components!
  }
}

func buildComponentArray() {
  componentArray.append( rowOfComponents( yOffset: 190, components: [
  UIComponentLocationStruct( control: secondsLabel.frame, xOffset: 0, yOffset: 0 ),
  UIComponentLocationStruct( control: tenthsLabel.frame, xOffset: 250, yOffset: 0 )] ) )
}

func updateControlLocations () {
  let width = self.view.bounds.width
  let xOffset: Int = Int( (width - 280) / 2 )
  for i in 0 ..< componentArray.count {
    for ii in 0 ..< componentArray[i].components.count {
      var frame:CGRect = componentArray[i].components[ii].control
      frame.origin.x = CGFloat( xOffset + componentArray[i].components[ii].xOffset )
      frame.origin.y = CGFloat( componentArray[i].yOffset + componentArray[i].components[ii].yOffset )
      componentArray[i].components[ii].control = frame  // <-- This is not updating the UI element
    }
  }
}
```

I ended up going through each item individually, which works, but there's probably a better way to do this.

Comment: How about changing `control: CGRect` to `control: UIView` to maintain a reference to the control itself (and not just grab a copy of its layout box)?

Comment: Because I have UIPickerView, UIButton, UILabel, UISwitch, etc, all of which don't have UIView immediately as a super-class.  But they all do have frames, which are CGRect.

Comment: They all have frames _because they are all subclasses of UIView._ Some of them are subclasses of UIControl, yes, but UIControl is itself a subclass of UIView. You can refer to any one of them as a UIView.

Comment: Finally got back to this: Changing it to UIView worked.  Thanks!